# How can I use Atom editor on AWS' amazon linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, atom-editor

I'm just beginner at Ruby & Rails.

I make a instance with Amazon Linux.
and someone talks "Use Vim".
but I want to use Atom editor.

Can I use Atom on Amazon Linux?
Or I just make new instance with Ubuntu Server?

and one more things!
Can I control only with Command Line??

Comment: The `atom` tag you used for this question is in relation to the XML based syndication format, as this post is about GitHub's Atom Editor I have changed the tag to `atom-editor`. If you are not sure about how to use tags, please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1)

You can X forward over SSH to use the Atom GUI.
Typically all you need to do is `ssh -X yourserver.com`, and then run atom from the command line.

I don't know your setup enough to determine if just that will work, or if you need to enable XForwarding, or even install X, etc. This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine

As far as I know Atom is only GUI. I'm sure you can find some CLI for it that somebody made, but at that point you should just use Vim.

Keep in mind X forwarding will probably be very slow. You have another alternative:

2)

sshfs can be setup to create a virtual filesystem through ssh to your server. You can then run Atom on your local machine and edit remote files. It's super easy and this guide explains it best: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

Answer (score 0):

I am running Amazon Linux 2 and it has a GUI. I followed these instructions and I can run Atom from my Amazon Linux 2 desktop: https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-atom-text-editor-on-centos-7-6